# app not working correctly after getting flutter dio unknown error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

After getting unknown error while using Flutter dio, did anyone get the error that some streams get an unkown error popup even though the application is working correctly? Can such situations occur because the request has not been completed yet and we use methods such as singlewhere because the lists are empty?

I can't share a code sample because it's a company project. But can someone who has seen this problem before or knows what causes it to help?

[Handler](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbW8D.png)

Answer (score 0):

This error is happen at dio version ^5.0.1
After downgrade the version, it will be fine.
Mine is
retrofit: ^3.3.1
retrofit_generator: ^4.2.0
dio: ^4.0.6

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).